# Creating "Welcome <username>" special menu items

Tags: 7, routes

I want to create special menu items with title "Welcome ". I want to make it as special menu item (without link to any node), that shows sub-menu on hover. For that I have used [Special Menu Items](https://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items) module and is working fine.

But I am not able to figure out how to create dynamic menu title in form 
"Welcome Username".  I have tried using [Menu Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token) module as well, but it didn't work. It just displays token as it is.

Any suggestion how can I achieve this using module or programatically.

-- Many thanks for your time.

Comment: _"I have tried using Menu Token module as well, but it didn't work"_ That module works well for me in dozens of projects, could you expand on what doesn't work?

Comment: It just shows token as it is, without replacing with actual value.

Comment: And you've definitely got the "Use tokens in title and in path" box checked, and have selected an option for "Methods for Nodes" or "Methods for Users" to invoke the tokens?

Comment: Yes, I followed that.

Comment: Looks like you've found a bug in the module then (like I say, that module works perfectly for me in dozens of projects). It would we a good idea to report the bug on the issue queue

Comment: Actually one thing I observed now is that, the token is replaced in Breadcrumb, when I navigate through one of its sub-links, but it doesn't replace in title.

Comment: I would imagine that's a conflict with another module/some custom code. If it's possible, try disabling the modules methodically until you find the one that's causing the problem. Also check any code in your theme which is altering menus

Comment: Is there any way programatically I can make this?

Comment: Well sure, the Menu Token module contains all the code you need to do that. But if it doesn't work in that module, it's not going to work for your custom code either. You need to find the root issue and fix that really

Comment: Ok, will try out.

Answer (score 1):

I used this on www.grupposportivo.be in a bootstrap nav bar

```
<!-- de inlog button en user print -->
            <li><?php global $user; if ($user->uid != 0)
                { print '<li class="first">' .t('').
                    '<a href="' .url('user/'.$user->uid). '">' .$user->name. '</a>
                    </li>'; print '<li>
                    <a href="' .url('user/logout'). '">' .t('Logout'). '</a>
                    </li>'; } else { print '<li class="first">
                    <a href="' .url('user'). '">' .t('Login'). '</a>
                    </li>'; print '<li>
                    <a href="' .url('user/register'). '">' .t(''). '</a>
                    </li>'; } ?></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the existing special_menu_items module. e.g. welcome_menu_items and put it in your custom modules directory. It is only 200 lines, so maintenance particularly if your requirements don't change should not be large.

Change this code adding '. check_plain($user->name);'.

```
  case '<nolink>':
    $tag = variable_get('special_menu_items_nolink_tag', '<span>');
    $title = $variables['options']['html'] ? $variables['text'] : check_plain($variables['text']) . check_plain($user->name);
    $variables['options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'nolink';
    break;
```

This will only give you the username, not the full name. You need to edit the profile to provide a full name. You might also want to check that $variables['text'] contains the work 'Welcome' before altering it.

You could debug $variables['text'] and submit a patch if there is a problem with this as noted by Clive.

Comment: But as it is special menu item with href="#", it links to nowhere, than what should be index of $items[].

Comment: <nolink>. Use dpm or Netbeans debugger to double check.

Comment: But won't it affect all special menu items with <nolink>

Comment: Looking at the code in special_menu_items you might be better off hooking function hook_link(array $variables) . It is only 200 lines of code. Copy to your custom and change the link code.

Comment: I take back this answer. I can't see <nolink> in the array and it only runs when the menu is being rebuilt - so won't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code snippet will help you.

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
 if($element['#original_link']['mlid']=='YOUR MENU ID'){
    global $user;
    $element['#title'] = $element['#title']. ' '.$user->name;
  }
    $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options'], array('attributes' => array('data-title' => $element['#title'])));
    return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";

}
```

Add this inside your **sites** > **all** > **themes** > default-theme > **template.php**

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest method is to use [Menu token](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token) module and add menu item with this settings:

- Title: `Welcome [current-user:name]`
- Path: `[current-user:edit-url]`
- Use tokens in title and in path: `checked`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we accomplished the same thing you are looking to do.  We used a custom module and hook_block_view. I've left the part relevant to you.  header_user_nav is our custom nav block at the top of the site.  We display the login/register link if the user is not logged in.  Once logged in [if($user->uid !== 0)], the block content changes.  The first li is the Welcome message plus the user's name.

```
function custom_module_name_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  if($delta == 'header_user_nav'){
    $block['content'] = '<ul><li class="login">' . l('Login or Register', 'user/login', array('query' => drupal_get_destination())) . '</li></ul>';
    $block['subject'] = '';
    global $user;
    if($user->uid !== 0){
      $output = '<ul><li class="username">';
      $output .= t('Welcome ') . $user->name;
      $output .= '</li>';**
      $output .= '<li class="profile">';
      $output .= l('My Profile', 'user');
      $output .= '</li>';
      $output .= '<li class="logout">';
      $output .= l('Logout', 'user/logout');
      $output .= '</li></ul>';

      $block['content'] = $output;
    }
  }

  return $block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the site current user token for menu tokens. See the screenshots it helps
you.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This doesn't work. It only rendered the token name in the menu.

Comment: Please select "user from content"  from dropdown "Method for User".  please follow the above screenshots